# Minitest Mocha Stub render action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, mocha.js, minitest

This is my create action:

```
  def create    
    if #something then
      flash[:sucess] = "sucess!"
      redirect_to app_path
    else 
      flash[:error] = "error" 
      render "template"
    end
```

this is my controller test

```
   should "fail if " do
    assert_no_difference '....' do
      patch :create,  #hash here
   end
```

I have stubbed a couple of methods using mocha, so I can't render 'template'. I want to stub the render action, so no template is rendered. Something [like this in rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/stub-template)

```
stub_template "gadgets/_form.html.erb" => "This content"
```

So far I've [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397052/in-rails-how-do-you-stub-the-render-method-in-functional-tests) @controller.expects(:render), but that did not work.

I've also tried [any_instance](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ClassMethods.html) with no success

```
ActionView.any_instance.stubs(:render).returns(false)
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `any_instance' for ActionView:Module
```

How can I stub render action using mocha with Minitest?

Comment: Why would you want to stub the render method? Views are not rendered in a controller test unless you explicitly use [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views).

Comment: This is part of the backtrace: 'app/views/instances/index.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_instances_index_html_haml___803308070840349184_59487160'' I don't have render_views.

Comment: Ah I missed that you are using minitest and not rspec. You might want to make it more apparent since the wording is kind of misleading

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `ActionView::Renderer.any_instance.stubs(:render).returns('')`